# Facebook Open Graph Tags not being scraped

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have thoroughly researched and tried EVERYTHING but for some reason facebook is not able to scrape my open graph tags from my site (Tried the debugger, reinstalling wordpress, wiping my host). I am running this same theme on other domains and do not have the issue.

Here is an example of a post that cannot be scraped

http://www.gojackal.com/humansdisappeared/

Please advise :)

Comment: Looks like your page just delivers no content at all. Requesting it with different user agents suggests that it does that when it doesn’t “like” the user agent used, probably a faulty “bot” protection. See if you have any plugins installed that do such a thing, and disable them. (Or add an exception for the user agent of the FB scraper; but since it seems to do more harm than good – your unexpected problem being proof – better just to do away with it completely. You don’t know what user agents the clients actual visitors are using might send, and you wouldn’t want them to see nothing either.)

Comment: Hmm don't think Plugins would be the issue, i tried deactivating Yoast and Re-testing but no luck. Is there a configuration within Bluehost I should be looking into?  Also, if you debug gojackal.com on the facebook debugger it grabs the open graph tags correctly it's just on any post that it cannot grab  anything..

Comment: I get the described behavior f.e. with http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://www.gojackal.com/humansdisappeared/ – no response at all from your page if I use their `Web-Sniffer` user agent (and for the FB scraper it seems to be the same), and a fine result when I chose “your user agent” from the dropdown. Plugins was just a first guess; it might be something else f.e. in the server configuration. Your next step should be to look into the server log files (access and error) to try and find out how those requests are handled.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Do you recommend a developer I can just pay to fix the issue since I can't figure it out?

Comment: Talk to your server admin and ask them to take a look at the issue, if there’s anything on their part causing this. (And no, sorry, I don’t have any developer recommendations. If you need one, I’d suggest you either look locally in your area, or create a job offer on some board frequented by people who specialize in that kind of stuff.)